# Duvida com "menor" no Visualg

Tags: visualg

Comecei um curso de algoritmos e tô gostando bastante! Mas ultimamente venho me complicando bastante com a questão do "menor" em algumas situações. Segue a questão:

Crie um programa que leia o sexo e a idade de várias pessoas. O programa vai
perguntar se o usuário quer continuar ou não a cada pessoa. No final, mostre:
a) qual é a maior idade lida
b) quantos homens foram cadastrados
c) qual é a idade da mulher mais jovem
d) qual é a média de idade entre os homens

A única opção que não consigo fazer 100% certa é a letra C. Alguém pode me dar uma luz de como fazer? Meu código está assim atualmente:

```
algoritmo "semnome"
var
nome,sexo,resp: caractere
a,idade,menor,maior,s,menorf,c: real
inicio
c <- 1
Repita
   Escreva("Digite seu nome: ")
   Leia(nome)
   Escreva("Digite seu sexo [M/F]: ")
   Leia(sexo)
   Se (sexo="M") entao
      a <- a+1
   fimse
   Escreva("Digite sua idade: ")
   Leia(idade)
   Se (c=1) entao
      menor <- idade
   fimse
   Se (idade>maior) entao
      maior <- idade
   fimse
   Se (sexo="F") e (idade<menor)  entao
      menorf <- menor
   fimse
   Se (sexo="M") entao
      s <- s+idade
   fimse
c <- c+1
Escreval("Você quer continuar? [S/N] ")
Leia(resp)
Ate(resp="N")
Escreval(maior, " é a maior idade.")
Escreval(a, " é a quantidade de homens.")
Escreval(menorf, " é a menor idade entre as mulheres.")
Escreval(s/a, " é a média da idade dos homens.")
fimalgoritmo
```

Se alguém puder apontar meu erro, vou agradecer bastante. Dicas de como melhorar esse código também são bem vindas :)

Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a algums pontos:

- No seu código todas as variáveis numéricas são `real`, mas idades são inteiras, por isso pode usar `inteiro`:
- Note que tem 2x o mesmo condicional `Se (sexo="M") entao`, pode juntar isso numa única validação;
- Tem variáveis com nomes pouco sugestivos, como "a, c, s", pode melhorar isso;
- Pode entrar com todos os valores e fazer a validação ao final, vai deixar o código mais fácil de entender.

Dito isso, algumas mudanças:

```
var 
   nome,sexo,resp: caractere
   totM,idade,,maior,somaIdadeM ,menorIdadeF,c: inteiro

inicio
// inicializar os contadores
maior <- 0
totM <- 0
menorIdadeF <- 0
somaIdadeM <- 0

c <- 1
Repita
   Escreva("Digite seu nome: ")
   Leia(nome)
  
   Escreva("Digite seu sexo [M/F]: ")
   Leia(sexo)

   Escreva("Digite sua idade: ")
   Leia(idade)

   // primeiro o mais simples, a maior idade
   se (idade > maior)
      maior <- idade
   fimse

   // segundo sexo = M
   Se (sexo="M") entao
      totM <- totM+1
      somaIdadeM <- somaIdadeM + idade
   fimse

   // finalmente sexo = F, que tem mais validacao
   se (sexo = "F") entao
     // se a idade digitada for menor que a "atual" menor idade
     // ou se a menor idade for zero, que eh o valor inicial
     // atribui a idade digita para a menor idade

     se (idade < menorIdadeF) ou (menorIdadeF = 0) entao
        menorIdadeF <- idade
     fimse
   fimse

   
   Escreval("Você quer continuar? [S/N] ")
   Leia(resp)
Ate(resp="N")

Escreval(maior, " é a maior idade.")
Escreval(totM, " é a quantidade de homens.")
Escreval(menorIdadeF, " é a menor idade entre as mulheres.")
Escreval(somaIdadeM/totM, " é a média da idade dos homens.")
```

Note que, na idade feminina tem 3 condições, primeiro `se (sexo = "F")` simples de entender, depois `se (idade < menorIdadeF) ou (menorIdadeF = 0)`.

A condição `(idade < menorIdadeF)` também é simples de entender, se digitou uma idade menor que "atual" menor idade, substitui, mas a última condição `ou (menorIdadeF = 0)` serve para atribuir a primeira idade feminina digita a "menorIdadeF". Como assim?

A "menorIdadeF" foi iniciada com o valor zero, agora imagina que foram digitadas as idades femininas 25, 15, 6, nenhuma delas vai ser menor que zero, logo vai ficar com zero que foi o valor inicial, e está errado.

Uma alternativa mais "simples" que perminte remover o `ou (menorIdadeF = 0)` seria iniciar a variável "menorIdadeF" com um valor muito alto, por exemplo 9999, porque ai "teoricamente" qualquer idade "válida" digitada seria menor, mas tem 2 problemas:

- Não está sendo validada a idade, alguém poderia digitar 50000 e vai aceitar;
- Poderia nunca ser digita a idade de uma mulher, e ai a idade ficaria com esse valor "estranho", por isso zero seria um valor mais "aceitável", ou seja, se nunca digitou fica zero.

Se achar os dois comando `se` complicados, poderia juntar num único comando, mas ia precisar de mais um parênteses pois, primeira valida o  sexo, depois a idade:

`se (sexo = "F") e ((idade < menorIdadeF) ou (menorIdadeF = 0)) entao`